# Show that a function $f: A \to B$ is surjective if and only if it has a right inverse.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The textbook I'm reading from defines a right-inverse as follows:

> Let $f: A \to B$ be a function. A **right inverse of $f$** is a function $g: B \to A$ with the property that $f \circ g = id_B$ where $id_B$ is the identity function on $B$.

Now, I'm asked to show that $f: A \to B$ has a right inverse iff it is surjective. The author notes that I may use the axiom of choice in this proof. In other words, they say to assume that given a family of disjoint nonempty subsets of a set, there is a way to choose one element in each member of the family.

**Proof Attempt:** Suppose $f$ has a right inverse. So, there is a function $g: B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = id_B$. Now, choose an element $b \in B$. We observe that $g(b) \in A$ and that, by hypothesis,  $f(g(b)) = id_B(b) = b$. So, we have found an element of $A$ (namely $g(b)$) whose image under $f$ is $b$. Since the choice of $b$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $f$ is surjective.

For the converse, suppose that $f$ is surjective. We need to construct a function $g: B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = id_B$ for all $x \in B$. In order to do this, fix $b \in B$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists an element $g(b) \in A$ such that $f(g(b)) = b$. However, we note that there may be more than one element of $A$ whose image is $b$ under $f$ (i.e. there may be more than one possible candidate for $g(b)$). In order to isolate a single candidate for $g(b)$, we proceed by cases.

**Case 1:** The function $f$ sends all elements of $A$ to $b \in B$.

In this case, we may conclude by the surjectivity of $f$ that $b$ is the only element of $B$. Therefore if we pick an element $s \in A$, we may define a function $g: B \to A$ where $g(b) = s$. Then, we simply observe that $f(g(b)) = f(s) = b = id_B(b)$. Since $b$ is the only element of $B$, we may immediately conclude that $g$ is a right inverse of $f$.

**Case 2:** Only the elements in a proper subset of $A$ are mapped to $b$ by the function $f$.

In this case, we can divide the set $A$ into two disjoint subsets $R$ and $S$ where $R$ is the set of all elements in $A$ that get mapped to $b$ by $f$ and $S$ is the set of all elements of $A$ that are not mapped to $b$ by $f$. By the axiom of choice, I can select a single element $p \in R$ and simply let $g(b) = p$. This shows that for any element $x$ of $B$, I can always find a single candidate for $g(x) \in A$ such that $f(g(x)) =x$. Then, we can properly define a function $g: B \to A$ that sends any $x \in B$ to the single candidate $g(x)$ that we have chosen, and, by construction, $g$ will be a right inverse of $f$. This completes the proof.

Is my proof correct? This is the first time I've done a proof requiring the axiom of choice, so I'm wondering if I've invoked it correctly. Are there any ways that I could improve the proof or details that perhaps I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you start having difficulty right around this statement:

> By the axiom of choice, I can select a single element $p\in \mathbb{R}$ and simply let $g(b) = p$.

That is not the point of the axiom of choice. The axiom of choice means, intuitively, that we can make *infinitely many* choices all *at once*.
As such, your proof doesn't really highlight how to use the AC.

I'd phrase it as follows. Recall that AC has one of its formulations as follows.
If your textbook gave a different definition, it may be a good exercise to prove it is equivalent to mine.

> **Axiom of Choice.** Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a nonempty set, not containing the empty set. Then there exists a function $F : \mathscr{C} \to \bigcup \mathscr{C}$ such that $F(S) \in S$ for all $S \in \mathscr{C}$.

(Recall that $\bigcup \mathscr{C}$ is the union of all sets in $\mathscr{C}$, i.e., $\bigcup \mathscr{C} = \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{C}} S$.)
In other words, AC guarantees the existence of a function that, for a collection of sets, 'picks' an element from each set in that collection.

Now suppose that a function $f : A \to B$ is surjective. Then define the collection
$$ \mathscr{C} := \{ f^{-1}(\{b\}) \subseteq A \mid b\in B \}.$$
(Recall that $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ is the *set* of all $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.)
Since $f$ is surjective, none of the sets in $\mathscr{C}$ is empty. Thus we may apply  AC to it to obtain a map
$$ F : \mathscr{C} \to A$$
which picks one element from each set in $\mathscr{C}$ (note that $\bigcup \mathscr{C} = A$). Now define
$$ g : B \to A : b \mapsto F( f^{-1}(\{b\})).$$
That is, when given a $b \in B$, we consider the set $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ (which is nonempty) and 'pick' an element from it. This makes $g$ a right-inverse for $f$. As an exercise, try to write out why this is so.

Comment: Your prove is the simplest and interesting

Answer (score 5):

The axiom of choice is equivalent to Zorn’s Lemma that is more useful to prove a lot of results.

You can consider this set

$\Lambda:=\{(h,C): C\subseteq B, h: C\to A , f\circ h=Id_C\}$

This set is non-empty because if you consider $a\in A$ then

$(h, \{f(a)\})\in \Lambda \neq \emptyset$ where $h(f(a))=a$

You can fix a particular order $<$ on $\Lambda$ :

$(h,C)< (r,S)$  if and only if $ C\subseteq S$ and $r_{|C}=h$

You can verify that $<$ a partial order on $\Lambda$.

Now we consider a chain $X\subset \Lambda$

Then $(\cup_{(h,C)\in X} h, \cup_{(h,C)\in X} C)\in \Lambda $ and it is a maggiorante for the chain $X$.
So by Zorn’s lemma there exists a maximal element $(h,C)$  for $(\Lambda,<)$.
You can prove that $C=B$ in the hypothesis that $f$ is surjective.
If there exists an element $b\in B/C$ by surjectivity of $f$ there exists an element $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.
Then you can define $r: C\cup \{b\} \to A$ such that $r(x)=h(x)$ if $x\in C$ and $r(x)=a$ if $x=f(a)$.

So $(r,C\cup \{b\})\in \Lambda$ and $(h,C)<(r,C\cup \{b\})$ and it is not possible by maximality of $(h,C)$

Comment: I'm not sure if Zorn's lemma is the easiest introduction to the axiom of choice...

Comment: You’re right, but I wanted propose another way to prove the statement.

Answer (score 3):

The use of the axiom of choice actually comes in *after* the following sentence in your question:

> "...This shows that for any element $x$ of $B$, I can find a single candidate for $g(x)\in A$ such that $f(g(x))=x$...."

You can do that observation for **any** fixed $x\in A$ but that on its own does not assure yet the **existence of a function** $g:B\to A$  that sends every $y\in B$ to a suitable candidate.

For that last step the axiom of choice comes in.

One of its forms is:

> If $\mathcal P$ is a partition of $A$ then a function $\nu:\mathcal P\to A$ exists such that $\nu(P)\in P$ for every $P\in\mathcal P$.

This can be applied here on the partition $\mathcal P:=\{f^{-1}(\{b\})\mid b\in B\}$.

Note that this $\mathcal P$ is indeed a partition of $A$ **because** $f$ is surjective ensuring that $f^{-1}(\{b\})\neq\varnothing$ for every $b\in B$.

If $h:B\to\mathcal P$ is prescribed by $b\mapsto f^{-1}(\{b\})$ then for $g$ we can take the composition $\nu\circ h:B\to A$.

Also this way of working makes a split up in two cases redundant.